# TimeZone Offset is incorrect for "Egypt Standard Time" on Windows 10

Tags: c#, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

I am trying to convert an UTC date to "Egypt Standard Time", but calculated offset for summer time is different depending on the operating system version:

- on windows 10, the offset is +2
- on windows 11, the offset is +3  (this is the correct one)

This is the code that I'm using for the conversion:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Egypt Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset initialLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeUtc, timeZone);
```

dateTimeUtc is of type `DateTimeOffset`, with value:

```
    {10/14/2023 9:00:00 PM +00:00}
    Date: {10/14/2023 12:00:00 AM}
    DateTime: {10/14/2023 9:00:00 PM}
    Day: 14
    DayOfWeek: Saturday
    DayOfYear: 287
    Hour: 21
    LocalDateTime: {10/15/2023 12:00:00 AM}
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 10
    Offset: {00:00:00}
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 638329140000000000
    TimeOfDay: {21:00:00}
    UtcDateTime: {10/14/2023 9:00:00 PM}
    UtcTicks: 638329140000000000
    Year: 2023
```

And this is the result:

```
{10/14/2023 11:00:00 PM +02:00}
Date: {10/14/2023 12:00:00 AM}
DateTime: {10/14/2023 11:00:00 PM}
Day: 14
DayOfWeek: Saturday
DayOfYear: 287
Hour: 23
LocalDateTime: {10/15/2023 12:00:00 AM}
Millisecond: 0
Minute: 0
Month: 10
Offset: {02:00:00}
Second: 0
Ticks: 638329212000000000
TimeOfDay: {23:00:00}
UtcDateTime: {10/14/2023 9:00:00 PM}
UtcTicks: 638329140000000000
Year: 2023
```

In the result, the offset is +2 and should be +3.

I found that [Daylight saving time in Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Egypt) was changed recently and I assume that tis is the reason why is not working properly on Windows 10.

How can I calculate correctly the Offset for this timeZone on all operating systems?
Should I call some external service in order to get the correct offset?

Comment: Windows 10 should have the updated DST offsets. See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/daylight-saving-time-time-zone/egypt-2023-time-zone-update-now-available/ba-p/3794114

Comment: ^^ An _updated_ Windows 10. If it was installed before the change and then never updated (which is highly unlikely, though) then the change is not active _on that particular installation_.

Comment: This highlights one of the reasons why it is strongly recommended that internally all applications use UTC

Comment: ^^ and why Daylight Savings is such a pain where daylight does not reach.

Comment: @Sweeper, the updates are managed by the company, so I assume this update was not installed on company's computers and servers.

Comment: @ChrisBD, that's why we have the UTC date (converted from midnight user local time by the fromtend and sent as UTC to backend). But we need to do some calculations  on backend and because of this we have to convert back the UTC to local

Comment: @MG7 - surely all calculations should be in UTC time and date, otherwise you'll need to allow for times that span application or removal of any summertime offset.

Comment: @ChrisBD - (*sigh*, yet again.) "Always use UTC" is misguided advice that needs to stop.  There are plenty of cases for local time.  Specifically, UTC is for timestamping (i.e. logs, time of purchase, etc.).  Local time is for scheduling future events, and any calculation that involves business logic.  For example, "The sale ends next Tuesday" cannot be performed strictly in UTC, because the offset between local and UTC might change between now and then.  Especially in this situation, where the government has made a rule change.  Another example is calculating age from birthday. No UTC there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Sweeper and Fildor mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444063/timezone-offset-is-incorrect-for-egypt-standard-time-on-windows-10#comment136529545_77444063), the issue is not related to the OS version, but is because one machine has applied [the correct Windows Update](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/daylight-saving-time-time-zone/egypt-2023-time-zone-update-now-available/ba-p/3794114) and the other machine has not.

When a government makes changes to its rules for time zones (including standard time, daylight saving time, and the transitions between), Microsoft issues updates to Windows to account for the change.  Ideally, all computers are receiving Windows Updates automatically.  If not, then they would not be able to know what change the government has made.

When using `TimeZoneInfo` in .NET, the time zone data is taken from the underlying operating system.  On Windows, that means .NET is impacted by these time zone updates delivered through Windows Update.  A similar situation is true for MacOS and Linux, but the updates stem from [the IANA tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) rather than Microsoft.

So, to answer your question directly - apply the latest Windows Updates (or the specific KB's mentioned in [the announcement blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/daylight-saving-time-time-zone/egypt-2023-time-zone-update-now-available/ba-p/3794114)), to the machine that's getting the wrong time zone offset, and it will resolve the problem.

As an alternative approach, you can consider writing your application such that *you* are in control of the time zone data rather than the operating system. The best way to do that in .NET is to use the [Noda Time library](https://nodatime.org/).  See [Updating the time zone database](https://nodatime.org/userguide/tzdb) in that library's documentation.  If you take this approach, then you would need to periodically get a new `NodaZoneData` file and apply it to your application.  You could do that as you build updated versions of your application, or your application could self-contain the logic for fetching time zone data.  Either way, the implementation is up to you.